# How to lock a code block based on a certain condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-scraping, locking, conditional-statements

**EDIT:** I've added a table example (see google sheets link) and how the resulting apple object should look like.

I've programmed a multi-threaded web scraper using Jsoup, which extracts information from a website and saves it into a map. The main thing which i can't get to work is that the program does NOT connect to the website if it already scraped a certain information.

**Information about the program**

It extracts information from a table on a website and starts a thread for every word in the table.

So the threads get started with a certain word as class member. Every thread also has the same ConcurrentHashMap object. My plan was to check if the word already exists in the map as key.
If NOT, it should connect to a website to get information about the word, add some data to it and put it in the map afterwards.
If the map already contains the word, the thread should get the value from the map and only add the data to it.

**So the main goal is NOT to connect to the website twice for the same word.**

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**Main class**
Starting a thread for every word in the table. "element" contains the word and an url for more information about the word.

```
for (Element element : allRelevantTableElements) {
    executorService.execute(new Worker(element, data, concurrentMap));
}
```

**Worker class**
1.  Check if word is already in map.
2a. If it is in map, just add data to it.
2b. If it is not in map, scrape information from website and then add data to it.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

MyWebScraper scraper;
Element element;    
String data;
ConcurrentMap<String, Fruit> concurrentMap;

public Worker(Element element, String data, ConcurrentMap<String, Fruit> concurrentMap) {
    this.element = element;
    this.data = data;
    this.concurrentMap = concurrentMap;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    Fruit fruit;

    if (concurrentMap.containsKey(element.text())) { 
        fruit = concurrentMap.get(element.text());
        fruit.addData(data)
    } else {            
        scraper = new WebScraper("http://fruitinformation.com" + element.attr("href"));
        scraper.connect();
        fruit = scraper.getInformation();
        fruit.addData(data)
    }

    concurrentMap.put(element.text(), fruit);
}
}
```

**Example**
Lets say the table looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JF8sh8Sp9y0SV3Xb5mlISgcJp5s_DhaSp3KbnQLa248/edit?usp=sharing

The main class will start 3 threads:
Thread 1: Element contains "Apple" and the suburl "/apple",
Data contains "1,20€"
Thread 2: Element contains "Orange" and the suburl "/orange",
Data contains "2,40€"
Thread 3: Element contains "Apple" and the suburl "/apple",
Data contains "1,50€"

The problem is that all threads run almost simultaneously, so thread 1 and 3 will both check if "apple" is already in the map and BOTH will get false as result. So they BOTH connect to the website fruitinformation.com/apple and get the basic information about apples which i only need once. Then BOTH will add their data to the returned object and put it in the map, but thread 1 will do that first with "1,20€" and then thread 2 overrides the "1,20€" apple with his "1,50€ apple as the value.

However the goal is that only ONE apple thread connects to the website and adds his data(for example 1,20€) and then the other one realizes that an apple object already exists in the map and only adds his data(1,50€) to the existing apple. The fruit objects have Lists for that.
So the resulting map entry should look like this:
`Key=Apple , Value= Fruit["Apple", basicInformationFromWebsite, List["1,20€"; "1,50€"]]`

The other thread (orange) should run totally unaffected by all this.
So all different fruits should run simutaneously but elements with the same fruit have to respect each other somehow.
Is there a type of synchronization which only blocks instances with the same fruit names, but doesnt block any other instances?

---

I've read a lot about synchronization, locks, etc but can't find a solution for my problem.
It would be nice if someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: _... and starts a thread for every word in the table._  That sounds like a bad idea.  A better idea would be to submit a _task_ to an `ExecutorService` for every word in the table.  Configure the ExecutorService with an appropriate number of threads for the computing and I/O capacity of the machine you're running on.

Comment: As you can see in my "Main" class, I've used an ExecutorService already. Maybe its worded confusingly, but "starts a thread" means "submits a task to the ExecutorService to be processed in a thread". I'm using a FixedThreadPool of 20, because more connections get blocked by the website.

Answer (score 0):

XY problem. Synchronisation won't fix this. Even assuming you could implement it, the second thread would just be blocked by the first and then proceed to do the unwanted crawl.

You could add a Set of words that have begun to be processed, or add a dummy element into the map that shows it is already being processed although not complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the total list of words *first*, then just pre-populate the map with placeholder values.  then you only need to start threads for each of the keys in your map.

Comment: Yes i parse the table of words first. However just starting threads for each map key is not working, because most words exist multiple times in the map and each time they have different data in another column, which i need to add to the object in the value of each key.

Comment: @MasterReY - that doesn't make sense, if you are using the fruit name as the key to the table, you can only have one fruit per name.

Comment: Yes, but in the table lets say i have the word "apple" multiple times. Each time it has different data in a certain column in the same line. (1,20€, 1,50€, 2,30€, ....) As in Peter sold an apple for 1,20€, Lisa sold an apple for 1,50€ etc. So the goal is to have the word "apple" as key in the map and a single apple object which contains some basic information about apples from the website AND all the different data (1,20€, 1,50€, etc). The fruit object has a list for that.

Comment: @MasterReY - i'm not seeing the problem.  parse the table and populate the map with the fruit name and table info.  then run a bunch of threads to scrape the basic fruit information.  again, no complex coordination needed.

Comment: The problem i'm seeing is that the basic fruit information gets scraped multiple times for the same fruit. I guess i could have a list of "already scraped" fruits in the main thread and then start the threads with a boolean to tell it that the basic information for this specific fruit is still needed or that it doesnt need to scrape it anymore when it was already in the list. I just thought there is a way to handle this INSIDE the parallel threads. I guess its not possible and i have to use a list outside.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MasterReY - what you want to do _is_ possible, it's just not necessary.  apparently i'm not explaining the (simpler) alternative very well, however.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my answer is in line with how you've structured your app, but what follows is the "correct" way of handling your type of problem which is quite common in parallel applications.

It is certainly doable to obtain what you want and avoid "double" computation. I suggest you read *java concurrency in practice* and more specifically chapter 5 I think it is, where they have to do memoization of calculations (huge computations) and also have to avoid two threads calculating the same number.

Some tricks you can apply are to use *putIfAbsent* (method for only putting an item into a map if it does not already exist). More to the point however I suggest you store *Futures* in your map instead. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html
They represent the result of a computation and then you will both have the computation ongoing and be certain that it will not be computed twice yet you will still get the result for both threads as you just call future.get() which blocks until a result is received. I will not go into much detail as it is in fact shown very nicely in the java concurrency book.

So something like (pseudocode)

```
if !map.containsKey(word) {
    Future f = new Future(word)
    map.putIfAbsent(word, future<curWord>)
    f.get()
} else {
    Future f = map.get(word)
    f.get()
}
```

Comment: The first paragraph isn't clear. What 'this' are you referring to? The user's proposal? What follows in your answer?

Comment: What follows in the answer. I've corrected, so hopefully it should be clearer now.

Comment: 'This is the "correct" way of handling your type of problem' still reads like you're endorsing the OP's suggestion in the first paragraph. I suggest you use something like 'as follows' instead of 'this'.

Comment: Hmm... I did this in a previous version of the program but discarded that idea because it didnt work. I dont really remember the problem anymore. I know I've already used Callables for the threads, submitted them to the ExecutorService and put the returned Futures in a list. Then i iterated over the list of Futures and processed the results. This was probably the wrong approach using Futures, so i'll look into your suggestion and experiment with them again. If i understand you correctly you suggest using a map to store the words together with the futures and then add the objects to a 2nd map?

Comment: Whether to use Callable or Runnable you will probably know best as it depends on how you want to use your results. But yes as you state the idea is to use a map of words (keys) and futures (values). These futures of course are currently running so whenever a thread/task tries to compute result for a word that has already been seen it simply waits for the existing future to finish instead of adding a new one! My pseudocode is not spot on, So yeah, check out the book I suggest.